# TypeError: terminated [cause]: SocketError: other side closed in fetch Nodejs

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, undici

I got this error when I keep fetching an external API, I am simply calling:

```js
await fetch(url, method: "POST", headers:headers, body: JSON.stringify(payload))
```

```
TypeError: terminated
    at Fetch.onAborted (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11442:53)
    at Fetch.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Fetch.terminate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10695:14)
    at Object.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11537:36)
    at Request.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8310:31)
    at errorRequest (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10378:17)
    at TLSSocket.onSocketClose (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9811:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at node:net:337:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:631:7) {
  [cause]: SocketError: other side closed
      at TLSSocket.onSocketEnd (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9790:26)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1376:12)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
    socket: {
      localAddress: '172.17.0.2',
      localPort: 48798,
      remoteAddress: '13.232.157.196',
      remotePort: 443,
      remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
      timeout: undefined,
      bytesWritten: 1594938,
      bytesRead: 12318698
    }
  }
}
```

I have read [SocketError: other side closed](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/583), however, I am still very confused how can I solve it or get more hint on this error.

How can I fix it or trace where's wrong with my request?

Comment: Sounds like the *server* is closing the connection unexpectedly. You aren't going to be able to fix that on the client

Comment: I have asked the Api provider, they said it's because the data is too large lead to socket closed, is there anyway I can gzip the response? @JaredSmith

Comment: I mean, probably, but is the API provider going to decompress it on their end? There's probably an easier solution.

Comment: The provider just asked me to able the gzip, like `--compressed` in linux-curl, however, I don't know how to do it in Nodejs. @JaredSmith

Comment: Did you try googling ["how to gzip in node.js?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+gzip+in+nodejs&oq=how+to+gzip+in+nodejs&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIKCAEQABgIGA0YHtIBCDQ3OThqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Because the number one hit is a Stack Overflow Q&A...

Answer (score 2):

*Note: everything below is unsure. I don’t have the Node knowledge for this.*

We encountered this issue at work (Node 18.x, AWS Lambda environment), and what we found out is Node sometimes closes the TLS connection too soon.

According to an [`undici` issue](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/583#issuecomment-855384858), the response must always be consumed (before ending your current JS execution block, if I properly get it).

So, this may sometimes fail:

```js
const myFetcher = async (url) => await fetch(url)
```

This may be a workaround:

```js
const myFetcher = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url)

  /**
   * Response body must be consumed to avoid socket error.
   * https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/583#issuecomment-855384858
   */
  const clonedRes = res.clone() // alternative: `res.clone()`

  return clonedRes; // if using previous alternative: `return res`
};
```

This may be another one if you don’t need to use the response furthermore:

```js
const myFetcher = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url)

  /**
   * Response body must be consumed to avoid socket error.
   * https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/583#issuecomment-855384858
   */
  res.body.getReader() //

  // There’s no point returning `res`: it is consumed by the previous line.
};
```

I think the workarounds work because the response body is consumed inside the function definition (= in `myFetcher`) instead of outside like in the first example. I found a note about a TCP mechanism named backpressure on the [MDN `Object.clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone), and it seems Node also has a [full guide](https://nodejs.org/en/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) on it. My understanding of it in our case is that the `fetch` response is big enough to have Node slowing down the process of it: basically it says to the other side (either the system behind the URL called by `fetch` either an internal part of Node holding the response in memory/buffer) “can you wait one moment before we finish our transaction?”, and the remote part maybe can’t wait, so it gives up, and this error is thrown. That’s why consuming the body as soon as possible *might* solves this.

When looking at the stack, we have only [one place](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/blob/f1d7ada7eb2292932065a7c9ab23569b8a6e1720/lib/client.js#L433-L434) referring “other side closed” [in Node](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Anodejs+%22other+side+closed%22&type=code), and I guess that it’s not easy to isolate the exact *fail* leading to this behavior.

By looking for the stack trace line saying `at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:631:7)`, I found a [pull request in Node core](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/pull/1540) to address our exact issue. According to the PR author and a [commenter](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/pull/1540#issuecomment-1731730156), Node doesn’t comply a lot with the [part of the HTTP RFC about Message Body length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3), and apparently it’s currently [not fixed neither in Node 20](https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/1490#issuecomment-1746460844).

(I may be all wrong, of course.)

Comment: that'd be a great solution if it worked